# Adding more information to Gramps Descendant Reports

Tags: gramps

I’m trying to add more information to my Descendant reports. Nothing is working for me when trying to add a birth date and a residence for example.

I open reports, descendant reports, go to the display tab, and begin to type as per the information online. I have added $b, $B and $a[residence] as examples. The only code that seems to be working is $n.

Can someone give me a good example of how to add this information?

Comment: Which version are you using? How are you displaying the Descendant Report (PDF, printing, ...)? For me, $b and $B work fine, but I have never used attribute access here.

Comment: Hi, v 5.1.2-1
I'm displaying the descendant report in pdf. I have the fields filled correctly but when I enter $b or $B they just show a blank space on the report. 
If I was to use atributes do you know the correct $ code to enter in he display?

Comment: I'm using v5.1.3. I just tested the syntax for the attributes, and it's $a[XYZ], as given in the documentation. The capitalization of XYZ has to match the attribute in the editor ("Age" and "age" are different attributes).